# what is the greedy approach of this?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

[image]suppose we have some 2D boxes in a container surrounded by water. Unfortunately there is a hole in left hand side wall of container. The height of this hole is more than height of all boxes.length of all boxes is 1 m and their height is an integer.all boxes are put in one line.in every second the amount of water which insert through container is one square meter(take care our problem is in 2D context).we want to find how long it takes till a given box is one meter under the water.
is there any greedy algorithm to efficiently solve this?

Comment: This actually smells more like an integral calculus/rate-of-change problem than anything.

Comment: take care height of all boxes are not the same and we can not easily calculate the time needed for covering a box by 1 square meter water

Comment: You don't need a greedy algorithm, this can be solved in a single pass.  But you asked for a greedy algorithm, and I can't think of one.

Comment: Wait, I assumed the water comes in the hole.  Is that correct? Does the water enter via the hole in the left side?  I also assume the height of the boxes is an integer _number of meters_?

Comment: yes it comes via the hole and the height is integer number

Comment: Is the water able to flow around the boxes, or will a box cause a damming effect, allowing water to fill to its left before spilling over?

Comment: @MooseBoys: "2D context" answers the first.  By "The boxes are all put in one line" I assume they sit flat on the bottom and probably don't touch, thus causing a damming effect.  I also assume they're immobile/inflexible.

Comment: Oh!  I'd assumed that the boxes weren't touching and the water only had to cover the bottom.  Now I see we have to get one meter of water over an arbitrary box!  That's... slightly harder.  Only slightly however.  My confusion remains though, I don't see what "choices" there are to make, and thus how a "greedy" algorithm would apply.  I can only figure out how to find the answer quickly :/

Comment: if you think this problem has a quick answer give it.But i think you must calculate the time a particular box need to fill all previous boxes and next boxes till water can go above it,take care all boxes are touching their neighbours.

Comment: @amirveyseh When the `i`-th box has 1 metre worth of water, wouldn't it be true that all the `i-1` boxes before it have filled and overflown? So, you know that the total amount of water which entered the system = capacity of the first `i-1` boxes + 1 metre of water. So, you do one linear preprocessing pass and you can answer every query in constant time after that.

Comment: @Pradhan our boxes are solid so water can only be accumulated above  j-th box only when j-1-th and j+i-th boxes are taller than j-th box.so for an arbitrary box we should compute this spaces which I call them well!and ofcourse the time is related to next wells too...

Answer (score 0):

I think this algorithm can solve this in O(n).

from the i-th box we first go to the end of line to find the first box which is a higher than the i-th box.since differences between all boxes' height is at least 1 meter so water can't go further than this box.then we go from the i-th box to the beginning of the line.we save height of the i-th box in Max_Height variable.each time we find a box higher than this Max_Height we update Max-Height.so whenever we find a box shorter than the Max_Height we add (Max_Height - box's height) to our result.at the end we have computed area of all previous and next wells.so we just need to compute the distance between the first next higher box and the first previous higher box and add it to our result.
That's it.